# What is this A constant and where does it come from?

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-number-theory

[image: Can anyone tell me where this Alog(t) comes from?]

I tryed to figure this out but I cant find what is this "A" in the book :/

I assume this Alog(t) has nothing to do with Borel and that it is just bounding of this log part but I dont understand how :(

Comment: “The book” is not very useful information. It would be better to say *which* book (and when you post images, you should credit the source anyway).

Comment: Well yes, I am sorry. Its "The theory of Riemman Zeta function" by E.C. Titchmarsh

Comment: $A>0$ is just some constant that's guaranteed to exist. It's just an explicit way of writing O notations.

Comment: @TravorLZH Hmm okay, but how is that O(log(t)) occured?

Comment: By Euler-Maclaurin formula, it is not difficult to show that $|\zeta(\sigma+it)|\ll|t|^\alpha$ for some $\alpha>0$ and all $\sigma\in\mathbb R$